# Draggable legends are not working on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used to drag plot legends using the command below:

```
leg= plt.legend(fontsize=12)
leg.draggable()
```

Now it is not working on all version of matplotlib from 3.1.0 to 3.3.2, after I updated anaconda packages automatically, as it shows this error:

```
    leg.draggable()
AttributeError: 'Legend' object has no attribute 'draggable'
```

How can I fix this?!

Answer (score 1):

`Legend.draggable()` was [deprecated in v.3.0.0](https://matplotlib.org/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.0.0.html#classes-methods-functions-and-attributes) in favor of `Legend.set_draggable()`

Comment: I found this suggestion online, But it doesn't work. it gives this error (In my case anyways) : Legend.set_draggable()
NameError: name 'Legend' is not defined

Comment: `Legend` is the class of the object returned by `plt.legend()`. In your code, you would write `leg.set_draggable()`

Answer (score 0):

`Legend.draggable` is depricated, use this solution instead:

```
leg= plt.legend(loc='upper center', ncol= 4, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0, fancybox=True, edgecolor="k", fontsize=12)
leg.set_draggable(state= 1)
```

You must turn on legends by `state=1` otherwise you will get an error.